# why cant my pointer access the member elements of the structure

Tags: c, pointers, structure

The compiler spits out error saying can't convert "int to lin" and can't convert
"double to lin" when clearly my pointer is pointing to the right location.

```
typedef struct lin
{
    int data;
    float next;
}ode;

void main()
{
    ode*head;
    ode a;
    head=&a;
    *head=9;
    head++;
    *head=10.5;
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Please learn to use an orthodox indentation style and do not put multiple statements on a single line.

Comment: Try `*head=9;
    head++;
    *head=10.5;` --> `head->data = 9; head->next = 10.5;`

Comment: Yes, `head` points to `a`, so you could assign `head->data = 9;` and `head->next = 10.5;`.  The increment makes `head` point to an indeterminate location — you can't safely dereference it after the increment.  Or, with C99, you could write `*head = (ode){ 9, 10.5 };` using a compound literal; or even `*head = (ode){ .next = 10.5, .data = 9 };` which uses designated initializers too.

Comment: Are you trying to use a union instead of a struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to play with pointer only, then you need to do pointer arithmetic in such a way that you will never get into segmentation fault or type conversion error. Please refer following code-

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct lin
{
    int data;
    float next;
}ode;

void main()
{
    ode*head;
    ode a;
    head=&a;

    *((int*)head)=9; //typecast pointer to int because assigning int value here

    head = (ode*)((char*)head + sizeof(int)); //increase pointer by size of integer as after which memory for float is assigned

    *((float*)head)=10.5;

    head = (ode*)((char*)head - sizeof(int));//go to start of header again

    printf("head->data:<%d>\nhead->next:<%f>",head->data,head->next);
}
```

As this is somehow confusing and not readable to other programmer, you can simply use -> operator for assigning value to data members of structure.

Comment: i run your code and it gives error "invalid conversion for void* to ode*"and error "pointer of type void used in arithmetic"

Comment: you seem to get the question i was trying to find a way to move the pointer back and forth in a single structure variable so that i can access the member elements of the structure and manipulate their values                            since a pointer to an array can move front and back by just increamenting the value of the pointer so there must be a way for a structure pointer to move through the member elements since structure is also a continous block of memory with just different data types live in it

Comment: @ozzy I have run it on Linux and it is working fine. How are you compiling it? And which compiler are you using?

Comment: @ozzy-Try char* instead of void*, ignore warnings.

Comment: now it says error"cannot convert char* to ode* in assingnment"

Comment: i am using c free compiler and i am simply copying your code and pasting and then running it without any modification

Comment: Try new code as mentioned in answer, I have done some code changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused about *line numbers*. There are line numbers in your error message. Please consult them, and note the importance of *pasting the **entire** error message to StackOverflow*, next time.

If you were to inspect the lines which your error is complaining about (by *line number*; look for *the numbers*), you would see:

```
*head=9;    // an attempt to assign an `int` to a `lin`
*head=10.5; // an attempt to assign a `double` to a `lin`
```

Perhaps you meant:

```
head->data = 9;
head->next = 10.5
```

... or...

```
*head = (struct lin){.data = 9};
*head = (struct lin){.next = 10.5};
```

It's difficult to say. You could have even meant:

```
head = &(struct lin){.data = 9};
head = &(struct lin){.next = 10.5};
```

Think about this. Do you expect your compiler to guess which member you want to assign to? What if there are multiple `int` and `float` members to choose from? Which one should be chosen when you don't provide one?

Be grateful your compiler *doesn't* guess for you, like it will when you write `head++;` to instruct your compiler to advance the pointer one element forward, beyond the end of `a`. That is called a buffer overflow.

Which book are you reading?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to assign value to the data of the head this is what u need to do
`head->data=9;`rather than `*head=9`. since `head` is pointer to the struct lin then `*head` is the object of head and if you want to assign value to data member of object `object-name -> data-member = value;` is used. Similarly the for floating point here is 'head->next=10.5;'. you can refer to link [here](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-structures-pointers) and also if you can understand this is another [link](http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap12/subsection2.1.1.4.html)